# Never ending bluetooth notification

Tags: bluetooth

Using Windows 10, I'm getting a never ending toast notification from some bluetooth device that reads, "Add a device" "Tap to set up your 547C6942B94A"  It pops up about every 30 seconds.  If I click on it, I'm prompted with "Pair device?"  "Your app would like to pair to the device "547C6942B94A."  Enter a PIN to pair.  I've turned all notifications off.  Rebooting doesn't help.  If I turn bluetooth off, it stops, but I want to use bluetooth for headphones.  Powering off my headphones doesn't help.

Comment: So what other Bluetooth devices do you have enabled? That is a Cisco MAC address. Could be linksys or some other Cisco brand.

Comment: I have no other bluetooth devices enabled other than the headphones.

Comment: Lots of things have Bluetooth in them. By enabled, I don’t mean you actually connect them to your computer. It appears you have *another* device with Bluetooth enabled nearby and it wants to connect.

Comment: So there is potentially a cisco device that is stuck in "connect to me" mode?

Comment: It seems that way. Is it a laptop? Can you carry it away from these devices to see if the message quits?

Comment: I walked what should be well out of bluetooth range and it still happens.  Yet it doesn't happen when I take my laptop home.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that there are "additional bluetooth options."  One of those options is "Alert me when a new Bluetooth device wants to connect."  I'll never know what the mysterious 547C6942B94A device is, but that solved my problem.